# Change language in Codeigniter without cookie

Tags: php, codeigniter

I must create a system to change the language on a site by clicking country flags wihout using cookies

[Link to app on github](https://github.com/Tsogodar/numery-praktyki2)

In config set default language

```
$config['language'] = 'polish';
```

In view create two buttons to change lang

```
echo form_open();
echo "<button  name=jezyk value=polish>Polski</button> || <button  name=jezyk value=english>Angielski</button>";
echo form_close();
```

In controller Welcome

```
    $jezyk = $this->input->post('jezyk');
    $this->lang->load('message', $jezyk);
```

And everything works fine, but when I set english and click `Wyślij` button to generate numbers language gets back to default (variable `$jezyki` disappear and I dont know why).

Someone can help me? Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use any cookies?

Comment: project requirements :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Sessions,

```
$session = $this->session->all_userdata();
if ( !isset($session['lang']) )
{
    $this->session->set_userdata([
        'lang' => 'polish'
    ]); 
}

if ( isset($_POST['jezyk']) )
{
    $this->session->set_userdata([
        'lang' => $this->input->post('jezyk');
    ]);
}
```

And in view try to get lang session variable to set default language in button